# TrustGo categories my Android App as Low Risk

Tags: android, security

I have create a native android app. Uploading to Play Store is okay. However, TrustGo considers my app as Low Risk. I wonder what I do wrong in code.

Comment: You should probably ask TrustGo since they gave you the risk rating. Here is their Registration, Administration and Support contacts from the WHOIS database: lixuyang@gmail.com.

Comment: found solution, TrustGo detects classname as risk. That's pretty weird!